# groovy sublist removal

Tags: list, groovy

I have a list:

```
def clc = [[1, 15, 30, 42, 48, 100], [58, 99], [16, 61, 85, 96, 98], [2, 63, 84, 90, 91, 97], [16, 61, 85, 96], [23, 54, 65, 95], [16, 29, 83, 94], [0, 31, 42, 93], [33, 40, 51, 56, 61, 62, 64, 89, 92], [0, 63, 84, 90, 91]]
```

and a sublist

```
def subclc = [[1, 15, 30, 42, 48, 100], [58, 99], [16, 61, 85, 96, 98], [2, 63, 84, 90, 91, 97]]
```

I need to remove sublist from original list
I do so:

```
subclc.each{
   clc.remove(it)
}
```

but it throws an exceprion `Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

I do not understand where is problem and how to solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answers:**

For more groovyness and immutability, preserving the original list:

```
def removed = clc - subclc

assert removed == [[16, 61, 85, 96], [23, 54, 65, 95], [16, 29, 83, 94], [0, 31, 42, 93], [33, 40, 51, 56, 61, 62, 64, 89, 92], [0, 63, 84, 90, 91]]
```

And the java way, changing the original list:

```
clc.removeAll subclc

assert clc == [[16, 61, 85, 96], [23, 54, 65, 95], [16, 29, 83, 94], [0, 31, 42, 93], [33, 40, 51, 56, 61, 62, 64, 89, 92], [0, 63, 84, 90, 91]]
```

---

**Long answer:**

You are `Iterator`-ing through a list while changing the list. In this case you are better using `Iterator.remove()`, which is being abstracted by the foreach loop. 
When you change the list using the foreach loop, you bump into the iterator checks for modification using [`checkForComodification()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr.checkForComodification%28%29). Getting the iterator explicitly works:

```
list1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
list2 = [50,60,80]

def iter = list1.iterator()
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    def item = iter.next()
    if (list2.contains(item)) iter.remove()
}
assert list1 == [10,20,30,40,70,90]
```

Or you can use indexes. Note you need to control the index:

```
list1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]
list2 = [50,60,80]

for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
    def item = list1[i]
    if (list2.contains(item)) { list1.remove i-- }
}
assert list1 == [10,20,30,40,70,90]
```

Comment: I really don't like index manipulation inside a `for` loop. That's what `while` is for